# Why do enemies so frequently fight a Confessor in melee?

Tags: the-sword-of-truth

In the Midlands, or everywhere actually, people always try to kill those magical freaks with melee combat (send quads for Kahlan, send Blood of the Fold lancers for Adie). I have a feeling that they don't even try. The most sensible thing to kill a freak is to shoot them with <strike>an arrow</strike>, a hundred poisonous arrows from a few hundred paces. Or traps (since they can detect humans) and innocent meat-shields.

When they came for Kahlan, they send the first man in to be taken and none of them has anything more than melee weapons.

Why are they doing this? Why are they even try to get close to those freaks?

Comment: Addie is a sorceress, not a confessor. Also, Kahlan can't detect human beings. I think it would be best for your question to focus on one or the other, since the reasons for both are quite different.

Answer (score 4):

### By Kahlan's own admission, the quads *are* effective at killing Confessors

Every single Confessor, aside from Kahlan, was killed by a quad.

> Darken Rahl has used quads to kill all the other Confessors. I found my sister after they were finished with her. She died in my arms.

### So why were they so effective, even if using melee weapons?

Presumably, the quads used the same tactics as they used on Kahlan, including melee weapons. So why did it work?

First off, the quads sneak up on targets when they are unaware. Kahlan didn't know that a quad was a short distance behind her until Richard told her.

> Richard started over, keeping his voice low. “I was up there on a hill, above the lake. I saw you walking on the path by the shore. There are some men following you.”
>
> She betrayed no emotion, but continued to hold his gaze. “How many?”
>
> He thought her question strange, but answered it. “Four.”
>
> The color drained from her face.

Had Richard not intervened, they probably would have caught up to her before she even realized they were there. If they get the drop on her, she could just as easily be killed be melee weapons.

Second, there are four of them. A Confessor can only use her power on one person before being exhausted. It's not much of a stretch to think that they were so devoted to the cause of Darken Rahl that they were willing to risk one of their own lives to a Confessor's power in order to live.

(Also in *Legend of the Seeker* continuity, if you are confessed by a Confessor who is later killed, then you revert to your old self, so perhaps they figured it was an acceptable risk to let one be confessed, then have three to kill the Confessor before the confessed one can harm the others).

### Okay, so why not just use arrows?

It seems the quads prefer to use small weapons. In the fight were the quad attacked Kahlan, three weapons are identified: a curved knife and two short swords. In fact, when Richard first saw the quads, he didn't note any weapons on them. I suspect that it was in their interest to not let others see the weapons.

Say that the quads had spotted Richard before he realized they were stalking Kahlan. They could just pretend to be travelers and Richard might have ignored them. If they are carrying bows or crossbows with poison, that's a harder lie to swallow.

Historically, trained soldiers would also carry light weapons if they wanted to travel for long distances or at great speed, which the quads were. They were tracking Kahlan for at least two days with her not stopping to sleep or eat. Bows can be heavy, so lighter, smaller weapons mean less fatigue.

So the quads seemed to prefer light melee weapons over ranged weapons because they are lighter and easier to conceal. They are also experts at stalking their prey without detection, meaning it is likely they can kill a Confessor without them noticing until it is too late. And in the end, this method worked well enough to kill every Confessor, and likely Kahlan too had Richard not intervened.

<sup>All quotes from *Wizard's First Rule*.</sup>

Comment: I had just realized that they're not just wanting her dead. They want to do other things to her too. So, using a bow, she would be dead in a blink, and playing with a corpse won't have much fun.

Comment: Fair point, they did worse to Kahlan's sister after subduing her. Seems to me like more of an added bonus from their perspective; I don't think they would do that if they didn't think they could win a fight in the first place.